# Call to a member function mysql_fetch_assoc() on resource in

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me,i'm freshman on php, i have a function in  model.php

```
public function get_array_of_users(){
        $query = "SELECT login,email FROM users";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result){
            exit(mysql_error());
        }

        $row = array();
        for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($result);$i++){
            $row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }

        return $row;
    }
```

When i'm calling this function

```
  $result = $m->get_array_of_users();
    while($row = $result->mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
          ...
        }
```

it gives error
Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_fetch_assoc() on array in

Comment: foreach($result as $row){ // your stuff }

Comment: Stop using the deprecated mysql_* functions. They are removed as of PHP7. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements. Even more a reason if you're new to PHP.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois or mysqli

Comment: @Broebie PDO is more recommended as it has a better Integration of Prepared Statements and is database engine neutral. People which use MySQLi should also migrate to PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this with foreach as:

```
$result = $m->get_array_of_users();
foreach($result as $row){
    //your stuff
}
```

**Second**, If you want to use associative array than use this:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // note that it's deprecated function.
```

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` becuase `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: +1 for the side note giving him a choice also I would add in that side note that he needs to use prepared statements in the future when handling user input